# HANDLE vs void* function code style

Tags: c

I'm writing a library, and I have a function: `AddObj(HANDLE obj)`.
This function's purpose is to add different types of structs:

```
struct1
struct2
... etc
```

The question is:
**With regards to code style, is it better to use `HANDLE` or `VOID*`?** Or possibly something else?

Comment: I prefer `void*` (all lowercase) because I look at it and I know what it means; if I see `HANDLE` I have to fetch the library documentation ...

Comment: I fail to see how this is *not* utterly opinion-based.

Comment: There's just no difference.  Pick what you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would stick to `void *`. `HANDLE` is too generic. If you had specific types of objects and you wanted to use "HANDLE" to pass pointers to those objects it is less objectionable -- such as `WINDOWHANDLE`, `MODELHANDLE` that are typedef'ed to 'Window *`and 'Model *`, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

### You should use the method that GTK+ uses.

Instead of either of the methods that you have proposed, you should follow the lead of GTK+. They use an opaque struct pointer.

[Let's take a look at part of `GTKFrame`'s header file](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.10/GtkFrame.html):

```
struct      GtkFrame;
GtkWidget * gtk_frame_new              (const gchar *label);
void        gtk_frame_set_label        (GtkFrame *frame, const gchar *label);
void        gtk_frame_set_label_widget (GtkFrame *frame, GtkWidget *label_widget);
void        gtk_frame_set_label_align  (GtkFrame *frame, gfloat xalign, gfloat yalign);
```

Note that you can't accidentally pass a GTKWindow into a function that takes a GTKFrame. This method still retains all of the benefits of an opaque handle as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use HANDLE, it's because someone (probably one of your .h files) said `typedef void * HANDLE;`.

Personally, unless you are using a library which has defined its operations in terms of HANDLEs, I'd stick with void*. That saves other programmers the trouble of having to look up how HANDLE was defined.

Comment: HANDLE supposted to be opaque, so looking it up is unnecessary.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Opaque or not, if you don't know the definition you need to look it up.

Comment: In this case, yes. But HANDLE could have been intended to mean something entirely different in another context. (Perhaps it's a struct that describes a furniture component...) If you know how it's being used because this set of functions uses it that way, fine. I wouldn't recommend this as good style except when that kind of opaque abstraction is clearly intended.